# Excel VBA how can I find where two blank rows appear and delete one of those rows?

Tags: excel, vba, rows

My worksheet contains blank rows which I want to keep.

However it also contains groups of two blank rows and I want to keep one of them but delete/remove the other one.

END RESULT: sheet contains only single blank rows.

First attachment shows before (highlighted where two blank rows) and second attachment shows desired final result (worksheet only contains single blank rows).

What is the VBA code to achieve this please?

Something like:

1. select all
2. identify where two blank rows are and delete one of those rows

Thanks in advance!

[image: before]

[image: after]

---

In an attempt to improve the question and show my efforts with my own VBA code.... this is what I had got starting with a variable counter of 0 and when it gets to 2 it would delete a row, it sort of works as in it finds and deletes the desired row but it appears to run an infinite loop :(

```
Sub EmptyRows()

Dim x As Integer
Dim row As Integer


  NumRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  ' Select cell A2.
  Range("A2").Select
  row = 0
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For x = 1 To NumRows
  
    
     If Application.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow) = 0 Then
        row = row + 1
     End If
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     If Application.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow) = 0 Then
        row = row + 1
     End If
     
     If row >= 2 Then
        MsgBox "2 Rows!"
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        
     End If
     
     ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     row = 0
  Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: You could iterate through your rows and check them one by one; Every time the check returns an empty row, increment a counter variable by 1. If the row contains data, reset the counter to 0 again. If said variable becomes 2 or more after a row check, delete the row that was just checked and continue checking the next row (which is now the same index as the row you just deleted).

Comment: Try show your code attempt, it is not that difficult to solve.

Comment: Did nou try something  by your own? Anything, than asking for code... Then, if a cell is blank in Column A:A, could the code assume that the whole row is blanc, or this  must be checked?

Comment: Apologies, am newbie to stackoverflow.... yes have been trying on my own... shall I update my answer with my terrible code?! :) Or where do I put my code for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It will check if really whole analyzed rows are empty:

```
Sub deleteSecondBlankRow()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, rngDel As Range, lastR As Long, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).value
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = "" Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rows(i + 1)) = 0 Then
                If arr(i + 1, 1) = "" Then
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rows(i + 2)) = 0 Then
                        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                            Set rngDel = sh.Range("A" & i + 2)
                        Else
                            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i + 2))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
  Next i
  If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

The code only selects the rows to be deleted. If you check it and what selected is convenient, you should only replace `Select` with `Delete` on the last code line...

Comment: Yes this works good thanks.... I really appreciate it and I have been trying to understand it as well via Debug>Step Into. Thanks again :)

Comment: ok thanks for the insights... I have tried to improve my answer and done the check box as it certainly works on my end. Thanks again :)